# How do I get the difference between every now and every 12am on friday with dayjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, next.js

I need to make a timer that countdown to 12:00am every friday (Once it 12:00am I want to trigger an alert for a gift). I tried to do this myself with javascript, but I was unable to get it work, I then switch to a librabry called react countdown with dayjs,I was unable to make this work too.

The problem am facing is, making the counter start from 06:23:59:59 (12:01am Friday) and countdown to 00:00:00 (12:00am on Friday) every week.

This is what I've tried so far with dayjs and a library called react-countdown.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Countdown from "react-countdown";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import "@/components/Utils/Weekday";
import HomeTimer from "./HomeTimer";
import "./isoWeekday";
import "./weekday";

const CountTImer = () => {
  const [theNextFriday, setTheNextFriday] = useState("null");
  const [countDownStop, setCountDownStop] = useState(false);
  const [keyForIteratingTime, setKeyForIteratingTime] = useState("");


  const nextWeekthursday4_59pm = dayjs() - dayjs().add(1, "week").day(1).hour(23).minute(59).second(59);
  const thisWeekthursday4_59pm = dayjs() - dayjs().day(1).hour(23).minute(59).second(59);
  const everyFriday12_00am = dayjs() - dayjs().day(2).hour(0).minute(1).second(1);
  useEffect(() => {
    const Interval = setInterval(() => {
      if (dayjs() < Math.abs(everyFriday12_00am) || dayjs() === Math.abs(everyFriday12_00am)) {
        setTheNextFriday(Math.abs(nextWeekthursday4_59pm));
      } else {
        setTheNextFriday(Math.abs(thisWeekthursday4_59pm));
      }
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(Interval);
  }, [nextWeekthursday4_59pm || thisWeekthursday4_59pm || everyFriday12_00am]);

  const Completionist = () => {
    setCountDownStop(true);
    setKeyForIteratingTime(uuidv4());
  };

  const renderer = ({ days, hours, minutes, seconds, completed }) => {
    if (completed) {
      return <Completionist />;
    } else {
      // Render a countdown
      return (
        <>
          <HomeTimer
            daysLeftToSelectWinner={days}
            hoursLeftToSelectWinner={hours}
            minutesLeftToSelectWinner={minutes}
            secondsLeftToSelectWinner={seconds}
          />
        </>
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Countdown renderer={renderer} key={`${keyForIteratingTime}`} date={Date.now() + theNextFriday} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default CountTImer;
```

Whenever the countdown reaches 00:00:00, the keyForIteratingTime(uuid) change and the timer start again.

```
import { zeroPad } from "react-countdown";
import Parallax from "../Utils/Parallax";

const HomeTimer = ({
  daysLeftToSelectWinner,
  hoursLeftToSelectWinner,
  minutesLeftToSelectWinner,
  secondsLeftToSelectWinner,
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {daysLeftToSelectWinner && hoursLeftToSelectWinner && minutesLeftToSelectWinner && secondsLeftToSelectWinner && (
          <div >
              <div>
                <p > {zeroPad(daysLeftToSelectWinner)}</p>
                <p>DAYS</p>
              </div>
              <div >
                <p>{zeroPad(hoursLeftToSelectWinner)}</p>
                <p>HOURS</p>
              </div>
              <div >
                <p>{zeroPad(minutesLeftToSelectWinner)}</p>
                <p>MINUTES</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p>{zeroPad(secondsLeftToSelectWinner)}</p>
                <p>SECONDS</p>
              </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomeTimer;
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Maybe context would help solve the issue. What should happen when you run this after Friday at 12 am?

Comment: I want an event to fire, but I want it to always rerun after again after 12:00am. So when it reaches 12:00am, the countdown would be 00:00:00. And then restart again by 12:01am

Comment: So you probably want to check the difference with the next Friday, not just any Friday. https://day.js.org/docs/en/get-set/weekday

Comment: Yes, every next friday. So I can get every friday of the week with dayjs().day(5), but am unable to get the difference

Comment: `day(5)` doesn't return the next friday. It just sets the day of the week to `5`. You have to use `weekday`

Comment: Oh thats right it doesnot return the next friday. I cant find the weekday in the doc? I only find weekday that returns the name of the day

Comment: [weekday](https://day.js.org/docs/en/get-set/weekday)

Comment: It didnot work. It still give same result

Comment: `dayjs().add(1, 'week').day(5)`

Comment: Man, youre indeed a legend. Thank you so much for your support.

Comment: The solution seems not to work, I've edited the question. @KonradLinkowski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like this and it works perfectly, I use a library called dayjs.

```
 const todayDate = dayjs();
  const everyFriday12_00am = dayjs().day(5).hour(0).minute(0).second(1);
  const everyNextFriday12_00am = dayjs().add(1, "week").day(5).hour(0).minute(0).second(1);

  const winnerSelectionDay = (everyFriday12_00am < todayDate ? everyNextFriday12_00am : everyFriday12_00am) - todayDate;

  const days = Math.floor(winnerSelectionDay / day);
  const hours = Math.floor((winnerSelectionDay % day) / hour);
  const minutes = Math.floor((winnerSelectionDay % hour) / minute);
  const seconds = Math.floor((winnerSelectionDay % minute) / second);
  console.log(days, ":", hours, ":", minutes, ":", seconds);
```